# What is this longsword that turns into a high-crit chain- or whip-like weapon that I remember?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, content-identification

A while back I remember coming across a weapon from a 3rd party publishing RPG group for D&D that listed a weapon called either a Chain-blade or a Whip-blade, I don't really remember off hand. The important thing is that it has a critical threat range of 17–20 and a 10 ft. reach when it’s not a standard longsword.

Can someone help with what reference material this can be found in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am fairly confident that you are remembering the chainblade, which can be found in *Arms and Armor (v3.5)* from Bastion Press

The item's table entry can be found on page 8 of that book, which notes it as a reach weapon, in addition to having the increased threat range you mention and longsword typical damage dice and damage type. Its description can be found on page 16, and, - though it lacks a visual treatment - seems to strongly conform to the weapon you recall.

**Is it the chainblade, from *Arms and Armor (v3.5)*?**

Comment: That sounds like an excellent contender... is it possible to include a link, Or is that a "print media only" source?

Comment: @IsaacReefman Alas, the source material is not open content. Seeing as AOKost already came across this information in the past, I reasoned he might still have access to it. (I certainly know what it is like to own a large enough collection of something that one simply forgets the more obscure bits of the collection.)

Comment: Ah well. Maybe I can find someone with a copy of *Arms and Armor* so I can make a case to a future DM that there should be a chance of me finding such a thing in a 5e game... Not that he'd be obliged to comply, but at least I could make a better case if I could show it has been official content...

Comment: Thank you all... I did have it in the past but with the volumes of information I deal with on a regular basis I misplace things and google-fu didn't show any mention on here before, so thank you again for your patience and quick responce.

Answer (score 1):

For a similar, official weapon, see the spinning sword from *Secrets of Sarlona*, which is similar to a one-handed spiked chain, minus the actual spikes and plus a sword hilt. It has 10’ continuous reach, and a 19-20/×2 critical threat rating.

Note that no official weapon in the game has a base threat range of 17-20. Wizards of the Coast would have considered that overpowered and problematic. I find crit-fishing to be a wasteful strategy most of the time, which may work somewhat better with a 17-20 base, so I wouldn’t say overpowered, but I have to agree that it’s problematic: every crit-fisher ever should always use this weapon. The 17-20 threat range trivially blows any other possible weapon property out of the water for such a character. Attaching it to 10’ reach, presumably continuous, makes for what is quickly becoming the be-all, end-all weapon that basically every character should use—rather problematic for a game that wants to support all sorts of different characters.

Comment: I somewhat agree with your assessments, and _really_ appreciate the _Secrets of Sarlona_ reference! I'll make sure to use it!

There _was_ a weapon, I believe it was the bladed gauntlet, that had a 17-20 crit range, but it got nerfed in a 'errata' later... but the weapon I was inquiring about, even though the book had an update, it was never erratad... Even though the specific materials the weapon I was looking for isn't in an 'official' book...

I feel that the arguement that it's an Exotic weapon and therefore requires a feat to use should make a small balm to the complains but you could

Comment: Add more prerequisites to that specific weapon... BAB +5  or more, etc...